# Doubts about flow-model with respect to svg

Tags: html, css, button, svg

I have the following code:

```css
body {              background-color: black; }
.root {             background-color: aqua; }
.svg-container {    background-color: lightgray; }
svg {               background-color: red; }
.btn {              background-color: yellow; }

.svg-container, .btn {
    display: inline-block;
}
svg {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}

svg, .svg-container, .btn {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="root">
        <div class="svg-container">
            <svg></svg>
        </div>
        <button class="btn">Button</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I expected the height of `.svg-container` to be exactly equal to the containing `svg` = 60px. Further, the `.btn` should have been on the top side and not bottom. Another interesting thing with `.btn` is that it has a lot of space above it yet there some gap between the `.btn` and the containing `.div`.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using `inline-block` for your SVG element. Although it retains some block-level styling possibilities (such as the ability to explicitly declare vertical dimensions, paddings, and margins), it also shows some inline element behavior, such as **alignment to the baseline**.

If you look at your code snippet, the bottom of your inline-block SVG is flush with the baseline of the button text next to it. The additional space underneath all inline and inline-block elements are space reserved for descender on glyphs, like the hanging parts of characters like `g`, `p`, `q.